# Can JDBI bind additional values not in method signature?

Tags: java, jdbi

Is it possible to let JDBI bind more arguments than the ones specified in the method signature? For example:

```
@SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO derps (id, name, age) VALUES (:id, :name, :age)")
abstract void insertDerp(@Bind("name") String name, @Bind("age") int age);
```

Here I would like to add some code that can automatically bind some value to the `:id` placeholder. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by wrapping my methods in another method that adds the necessary field:

```
public void insertDerp(String name, int age) {
    insertDerp(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), name, age);
}

@SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO derps (id, name, age) VALUES (:id, :name, :age)")
protected abstract void insertDerp(@Bind("id") String id, @Bind("name") String name, @Bind("age") int age);
```